# Adding an Error Title and Message to JSON in PHP (Laravel)

Tags: php, web-services, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

```
$rules = ['email' => 'required', 'password' => 'required'];
        $message = ['email.required' => 'Email cannot be empty', 'password.required' => 'Password cannot be empty'];

        $v = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $message);

        $error = $v->messages();
        if ($v->fails()) {
            return response()->json(["code" => "400", "error" => ["code" => "10", "title"=>"" ,"message" => $error->first()
            ]]);
        }
```

The code above would return an error block in my JSON

```
error : {
    code: 11
    message: "Some error message"
}
```

However I would add a title field like below.

```
error : {
    code: 11
    title: "Some error title"
    message: "Some error message"
}
```

How should I do this validation? I need the `.required`

Can anyone please explain a little bit please?

Comment: Yes because your title is null

Comment: What do you want to be the title?

Comment: I want something like. for example: if the email is empty. I want the title to be "Email is Empty" and the message "Please fill out your email"

Comment: Can you try this `return response()->json(["code" => "400", "error" => ["code" => "10", "title"=> $message ,"message" => $rules]]);`

Comment: It wouldn't work. @aldrin27

Comment: Did you delete the `$error = $v->messages();`?

Comment: No i did not @aldrin27

Comment: Delete that because it will override the messages. Then change it to my code

Answer (score 1):

if you want this kind of validation error message format, I think you should build something a little bit more "complex" of what actually you have out of the box.

Here's what you get with a simple validation test.

This is the code I used.

```
Route::get('/', function () {

    $data = ['name' => ''];
    $rules = ['name' => 'required'];

    $v = \Validator::make($data, $rules);

    dd($v->errors());

});
```

... and that's the output.

```
MessageBag {#145 ▼
  #messages: array:1 [▼
    "name" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "The name field is required."
    ]
  ]
  #format: ":message"
}
```

**"Ok, so what I could do?"**

First of all, some assumptions. I see that you're taking only the first error. So, you would get something like this:

```
"The name field is required."
```

Working this way, you lose the "name" information. All you have is a simple string message. Not a big deal, considering what you want to achieve.

So, I would work different. There are many ways to do what I'm going to do, I will just show you a procedure.

First of all, let's take the first element of the array.

```
$errors = $v->errors();
$firstElement = reset($errors);

dd($firstElement);
```

I will get something like this:

```
array:1 [▼
  "name" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "The name field is required."
  ]
]
```

Now, starting from this you could do something like

```
$key = key($firstElement);
$value = reset($firstElement)[0];
```

To get the *key* and the *value*.

Finally, you should use them to build your response.

Here's an example:

```
return response()->json(
[
    "code" => "400", 
    "error" => 
    [
        "code" => "10", 
        "title"=> "Field $key is empty." ,
        "message" => $value
    ]
]);
```

Obviously I suggest you to create a class to implement the entire mechanism, in order to isolate responsibilities.

Hope it helps.